# Is it possible to execute npm commands using Django's execute_from_cammand_line function?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, command-line, django-2.0

Hopefully an easy question, but I'm wondering if you can run non python core commands from a script (such as `$ npm build` or `$ npm serve` etc) using Django's `execute_from_command_line()` function?

Surely yes! But how? What are the rules...?

Comment: No, absolutely not. execute_from_command_line is for ruining internal Django code. For anything else, use normal Python functions such as `subprocess.run()`.

Answer (score 1):

no, execute_from_command_line is for django commands only.

To execute normal external programs, use one of the functions defined in the  `subprocess` module:

```
subprocess.run(['npm', 'build'])
```